# Per-Project or per-Repo Scope for PAT's (Personal Access Token)

Tags: git, azure-devops

Can a Personal Access Token in Azure DevOps (PAT) be scoped per project or git-Repo? Are there any good alternatives?

We have some shared (internal) dev/test VMs where multiple developers use git occasionally (e.g. VS Code), each with their own PAT.

Since these developers can potentially have access to different projects, we want to make sure that the impact of a missing logout (due to stored git-credentials) would be as small as possible.

The Azure DevOps web UI does not allow scope PAT's per project or git-repo, but I was wondering if there are any other options, e.g. via API or CLI or some alternatives to this approach. Basically I'd like to have the PAT scope as narrow as possible. Didn't find any related feature requests neither.

Comment: Are they use the same account to logon to dev/test VMs? It would be better that, one account for a user.

Comment: They use the same Windows Account on those machines, but their PAT to authenticate. Unfortunately, we can't change the Windows Account part, since these are machines not in our Domain. We develop Machine control systems etc, so the VMs / PCs are very similar to the prod environment.

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if there are any other options, e.g. via API or CLI or
>   some alternatives to this approach. Basically I'd like to have the PAT
>   scope as narrow as possible.

You are right. If you want to use API or any other tool to achieve this, I'm sorry to say that this does not possible now. The UI of page while you are generating the PAT is the **unique** way to set the scope of PAT. For api, until now, it only support **List** instead of **create**, **put** or any other operate method.

But, if you limit the access in permission setting page, even give this account Token the full access, the PAT token still could not be operated to the relevant content which be limited in UI.

So, as work around, I recommend you can limit the access to per project or git-repo in the page to achieve what you want. For example, if you want to limit about the project access, you can change it in the **Users** tab of organization setting.

[image]

At this time, even the scope of token is full access, the user who is using this token still could not access the projects which not be allowed to access.

But still, this as disadvantage. If you just don't want this token be used to operate some special projects/repos instead of do not allow this user access the special project/repos in UI, this work around will not work for you.

I think the demand you want is suitable, you can raise your suggestion in our [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). Hope you could raise more suggestion to help build better Azure Devops.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, using the User settings in the Organization is not what we want. Users will have access to multiple projects, depending on their function / department etc. Just the PAT should be more specific/restricted, so that we can minimize the risk when setting up a test system, e.g. with a build / deployment agent installed on it. We don't want to add loads of service users just for this purpose. 

Will add a feature request in the development community.

Comment: @feustpat understood this actual demand. As I mentioned in my answer, this work around can achieve but has disadvantages. This will affect the team member access the project or repos normally. Hope your suggestions raised in Developer Community. After raised, you can vote and comment it. While has the enough votes, the product group will consider your suggestion as plan:-)

Comment: I had the same issue and ended up working around the limitation by creating a dummy user with the required project permission. This is such a clunky workaround, I hope MS adds the ability to add PAT with per-project scope.